Geometric mean in parabola
I just discovered a new feature using Geogebra, I want to know if it's already known or not, and I'd be happy to get many proofs.

$A,B$ are the lengths of any two parallel chords in the parabola, and they were connected by two straight lines as in the picture and then I drew a line parallel to them from their point of intersection and so you get $C$ Then it would be $A\cdot B=C^2$.

How are A, B and C defined? Please elaborate.

Okay, that makes sense. Do add this to your question! Questions should be self sufficient as much as possible.

May be a good idea to consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem#

And maybe https://nrich.maths.org/problems/parabella ?

James Tanton's Parabolic Multiplication: https://www.jamestanton.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Cool-Math-Essay_OCTOBER-2014_Parabolic-Multiplication1.pdf

Let $AB$ and $CD$ be two parallel chords of a parabola (see figure below), with midpoints $M$ and $N$. If lines $AD$, $BC$ meet at $O$, then it is not difficult to show that line $MN$ passes through $O$ (just use triangle similarity). Let $V$ be the intersection between the parabola and line $MON$.
Let then $EF$ be a chord through $O$, parallel to $AB$ and $CD$. In a parabola, the midpoints of parallel chords are aligned, hence $O$ is the midpoint of $EF$.
Segment $AM$ is called the ordinate to diameter $VM$, and a well known theorem states that:
$$
AM^2=4\cdot VF\cdot VM,
$$
where $F$ is the focus of the parabola (not shown in the figure).
If we now set $k=4VF$, from the above property we get:
$$
\tag{1}
AM^2=k\cdot VM,\quad
EO^2=k\cdot VO,\quad
CN^2=k\cdot VN.
$$
On the other hand, from the similarity of triangles $AMO$ and $OND$ we get
$OM:ON=AM:CN$, that is:
$$
(VO-VM):(VN-VO)=AM:CN.
$$
Inserting here relations $(1)$ we obtain:
$$
(EO^2-AM^2):(CN^2-EO^2)=AM:CN,
$$
that is:
$$
CN\cdot(EO^2-AM^2)=AM\cdot(CN^2-EO^2)
$$
and
$$
EO^2\cdot(AM+CN)=AM\cdot CN\cdot(AM+CN),
$$
whence the wanted relation immediately follows.

